# How to delay restart process in Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, reboot, restart

When we restart Ubuntu OS, it goes down, powers off (all connected devices also power off) and then quickly power up again and boots normally. Is there a way to add a delay between power off and power on. So that the system powers off, then wait for x seconds and then boots normally?

Thanks

Comment: for what purpose?

Comment: I think some boxes allow for it; I think it's a iLO option on some old HP/dell boxes anyway (a drop down menu that lets you pick from 2-3 options as I recall)...   it's the only time I've seen such an option anyway (Ubuntu isn't running, so Ubuntu isn't involved as it's hardware/firmware specific).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart options are limited to what the BIOS supports, since Ubuntu is not running during the restart.

If your BIOS supports that option, you are welcome to request (or contribute) the feature.

If your BIOS does not support that option, then it cannot be done as an Ubuntu setting. A third party (human or hardware) is needed to trigger the poweron.